# Mapping static file directories in ServiceStack

Tags: c#, mapping, servicestack

I'm building a self-host application in C# using Service Stack. I'd like the application to share content based on some configuration data.

During **AppHost.Configure** I'd like to read-in a configuration file and recursively share several directories. The directories may be local or shared folders depending on each element in the configuration.

For example, if my config looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "sourceId": "TEST1",
        "contentPath": "\\\\nas01\\files"
    },
    {
        "sourceId": "TEST2",
        "contentPath":  "d:\\files"
    }
]
```

I'd like the directories to be recursively accessible like this:

```
http://localhost/TEST1/....
http://localhost/TEST2/....
```

Reading the config file is no problem, really, I just want to know the right way to map these directories so I can use the built-in static handling capabilities of ServiceStack.

So I guess my question is:

**What's the right way, in Service Stack, to map a static content directory at run-time?**

Many thanks!

-Z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New support for FileSystem Mapping was added in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/0303650b328ece1fb11a05d220a3e8749210b411) which will now let you register file system mappings by overriding `GetVirtualFileSources()` in your AppHost, e.g:

```
public override List<IVirtualPathProvider> GetVirtualFileSources()
{
    var existingProviders = base.GetVirtualFileSources();
    existingProviders.Add(new FileSystemMapping(this, "TEST1", "\\\\nas01\\files"));
    existingProviders.Add(new FileSystemMapping(this, "TEST2", "d:\\files"));
    return existingProviders;
}
```

This change is available from **v4.5.5+** that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: Thanks very much for this! 

Does this technique work if new directories are added within the mapped paths, or would that require the FileSystemMapping object to be re-initialized?

Comment: @zorlack yeah it's not a pre-populated cache so it will find new files/dirs added at runtime.